# Adding Vorbis SPI dependency to Maven project

Tags: java, maven, javasound, vorbis

I want to be able to play ogg encoded files using JavaSound. I assume that the easiest way is to add dependency to Vorbis SPI and play it like a regular wave file. However my project is managed using maven, but vorbis spi is not available on public repositories.

What is the easiest way to add this dependency to my project? Is there maybe some kind of unofficially maintained maven repository where vorbis spi artifact does exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest is to import the jar yourself your local repository.**

- http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars

*If the developer use maven try to get the original POM when importing, or you will experiment dependencies issues.*

---

But the best would be to ask developer to provide a repository or to add the artifact in Maven Central (or Nexus OSS), but in the mean time you can setup your own repository using Nexus/Artifactory, and add the artifact inside:

- http://nexus.sonatype.org/
- http://www.jfrog.org/

Having your own repository can be really helpful. Specially if you are developing in team and building reusable components.

Comment: Does maven repository hosted somewhere on the server needs repository manager like the ones you've listed? Or will just a simple repository files exposing through Apache web server be enough?

Comment: You can create a repository without a repository manager. I remember using FTP, but seems that WebDav can be used too: http://www.beeworks.be/hosting-maven-repository-google-code/ - but without manager you can't update and provide an index !

Comment: Since it's an OSS component, I recommend you asking to put it in Maven Central / Nexus OSS. And in the meantime add it to your local repository using command given on maven FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Since I am struggling the same issue, I have performed a quick research and found following solutions:

1) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.soundlibs/vorbisspi

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
  <artifactId>vorbisspi</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.trilarion/vorbis-support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.trilarion</groupId>
    <artifactId>vorbis-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I haven't tested neither of them.